# Removing PCIe video card, trying to use integrated graphics

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, motherboard, pci-express

I inherited a computer that had a PCIe graphics card plugged in. I want to remove the PCIe graphics card and use the motherboard HDMI/VGA so I can free up the PCIe slot.

The problem is that the PC will not switch back to using integrated video, even enough to see the splash screen or get into the BIOS, so I ended up plugging the PCIe graphics card just to get into the BIOS.

I looked all around the bios looking for any kind of Integrated Graphics setting, and I found none. All I could find related to graphics is preference order of "PCIe/PCI" or "PCI/PCIe", and I tried both.

I also tried unplugging power, removing the CMOS battery, and fully unpopulating the card. I've tried all variations of just HDMI, just VGA, combinations, and unplugging and replugging.

I'm at a loss. Any other steps? If it matters, this is a slightly older Megatrends motherboard.

Comment: Not all processors have an iGPU. Not all motherboards support the iGPU functionality of a CPU that does have an IGPU but support the CPU. How can we answer your question with absolutely no hardware details?

Comment: I didn't realize that was a possibility. I just figured VGA was the dumb/simple backup for "you have no other option".

Comment: Make and model of PC?